# R: How to calculate probabilities for data transformed into normal?

Tags: r, self-study, normal-distribution, data-transformation

[image]

I basically don't know how to proceed with my transformed dataset.

I have a dataset of 500 observations, positive skew. I have used the bestNormalize package to normalise it (it chose Box-Cox, if that matters) and so now I have a nice dataset of new values, normal distribution. (The result is in a bestNormalise object, but I have also made a df from it, which is what you can see below.)

How do I calculate probabilities for new "original values" from this? I.e 113883785 equals 0.17045703 in the transformed data, and I can use pnorm to calculate the probability for 0.17045703, which should be the probability for 113883785 in the original dataset. But how do I go about getting the probability for 130000, or 586, or any number not exactly in the original dataset? Help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What Box-Cox transformation did you choose? (Box-Cox isn't just one transformation.)

Comment: Thank you for responding @Dave. I did not choose - the package that I have used (bestNormalize) has a function where it tries a number of transformations and picks the best one to normalize the data. The documentation says "Perform a Box-Cox transformation and center/scale a vector to attempt normalization".  (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bestNormalize/bestNormalize.pdf)

Comment: The Box-Cox transformation has a parameter. What is the value of that parameter?

Comment: @Dave, is it the lambda from: "Standardized Box Cox Transformation with 500 nonmissing obs.:
 Estimated statistics:
 - lambda = 0.2468158 
 - mean (before standardization) = 373.0962 
 - sd (before standardization) = 102.0227 " ?

Comment: That's the one! [Now do you know how that lambda is used to do the transformation?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) (Lambda is a Greek letter that looks like $\lambda$.)

Comment: No, not yet, but I am going to read the page you have linked and figure out! (Thanks for taking the time and trouble, Dave, I much appreciate it.)

Comment: Is there some reason why you needed to transform your data set to a normal distribution? If you just want to get probability predictions for "new" values based on the distribution of your `originalData` set, `ecdf(originalData)(x)` will return the cumulative probability for any new value `x`.

Comment: @EdM, thank you for your response. The min of my dataset is in the 50,000 range but  I need to calculate probabilities for much lower values. Ecdf gives zero probability under about 56,000 but if I transform the data into a normal distribution, I can calculate probabilities for any value (or at least I have a case for doing so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `predict()` function from the `bestNormalize` class to get the corresponding point in the transformed dataset.

Let's demonstrate with a known distribution (Gamma) and transform it to standard normal distribution. The following figure shows that the cumulative probabilities on the transformed data computed with `pnorm()` match with those computed with `pgamma()` from the original data, as expected.

```
library(bestNormalize)
x <- sort(rgamma(100, 1, 1))
BN_obj <- bestNormalize(x)
x.t <- BN_obj$x.t #predict(BN_obj, x)
plot(pgamma(x,1,1), pch=19, xlab='index', ylab='probability')
points(pnorm(x.t), pch=19, col='red')
legend('top', c("P(X<=x)", "P(Xt<=xt)"), col = c(1, 2),
       text.col = "green4", pch = c(19, 19),
       merge = TRUE, bg = "gray90")
```

[image]

Now, let's say we have a new data point `x_test` from the original dataset and we want to compute the cumulative probability using `pnorm()` from the transformed dataset.

- You can do it with `predict()` to apply the transformation to a new test datapoint  (taken from the original distribution)
- Then use `pnorm()` to compute the cumulative probability.
- It will be approximately same as the cumulative probability computed from the original Gamma distribution, as shown in the next code snippet.

  ```
  x_test <- 1.2345
  x.t_test <- predict(BN_obj, newdata = x_test)
  pnorm(x.t_test)
  # [1] 0.6891166
  pgamma(x_test, 1, 1)
  # [1] 0.7090198
  all.equal(pnorm(x.t_test), pgamma(x_test, 1, 1), tolerance=0.03)
  # TRUE
  ```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, @Sandipan Dey! I have just tried it and it has worked. Appreciate the help!